# Firestore Transactions and data contention about questions

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I try Android apps Kotlin , I have two data updating devices,
My one device Firestore increase number field by 40,
my other device increases Firestore number field by 30,

My first device:

```
authFireStore.runTransaction { transaction ->
        var docRef=refCacheTransaction.collection("test").document("doc")
        var dataDoc=transaction.get(docRef)

   updateMap.put("test",(dataDoc.get("test") as Long + 40 )) //increment field 30 number


   transaction.update(docRef,updateCacheDBDataCollection)
        return@runTransaction null
   }
```

---

My second device:

```
authFireStore.runTransaction { transaction ->
        var docRef=refCacheTransaction.collection("test").document("doc")
        var dataDoc=transaction.get(docRef)

   updateMap.put("test",(dataDoc.get("test") as Long + 30 )) //increment field 30 number


   transaction.update(docRef,updateCacheDBDataCollection)
        return@runTransaction null
   }
```

I searched the forum and the internet, but I couldn't find anything based on ending the transaction, actually, I found one method, but I couldn't do it. I want help from people who know.

The method I found:

```
  // TransactionOpins need, but BUT THİS İS  TransactionOptions.Builder() and error
    TransactionOptions.Builder().setMaxAttempts(5)  // try transaction query size
    authFireStore.runTransaction(TransactionOptions,Transaction.Function {
        //data here
        var docRef=refCacheTransaction.collection("test").document("doc")
        var dataDoc=it.get(docRef)



        it.update(docRef,updateCacheDBDataCollection)
        return null

    })
```

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOVSr0OsAoU][1]

I do not want to 7:00 7:30 transaction update

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a transaction when you only need to increment the value of a field. If you need to increment the value of the `test` field, then you can call [FieldValue.increment(l: Long)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#increment(long)), as in the following lines of code:

```
var docRef = refCacheTransaction.collection("test").document("doc")
docRef.update("test", FieldValue.increment(40))
```

If you need to increment the same field with different values, then you should add the above code into a function:

```
fun increment(value: Int) {
    var docRef = refCacheTransaction.collection("test").document("doc")
    docRef.update("test", FieldValue.increment(value))
}
```

And then call it, either with 40:

```
increment(40)
```

Or with:

```
increment(30)
```

Please note, the above operation is atomic. So you don't have to worry about inconsistent data.

On the other hand, transactions should be used, only when you need to read the value of the field first. Since you only need to increment the value without knowing/using the value, simply calling `increment()` will solve the problem in an easier way.

Comment: Hey Muhammed. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?